# Not just a simple custom Button

Tags: c#, wpf

How to create a custom button that would contain an image that changes depending on **IsExecuting** in **AsyncCommand**? It needs to be implemented without creating a UserControl, only by inheritance from Button (`public class CustomButton : Button`) and Style in XAML.

```
public class AsyncCommand : ViewModelBase, ICommand
{
    protected readonly Func<Task> _execute;
    protected readonly Func<bool>? _canExecute;

    private bool _isExecuting;
    public bool IsExecuting
    {
        get => _isExecuting;
        set => RisePropertyChanged(ref _isExecuting, value);
    }

    public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> execute, Func<bool>? canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => !_isExecuting && (_canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true);

    public async void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            try
            {
                IsExecuting = true;
                await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsExecuting = false;
            }
        }

        OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    protected virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(object? parameter) => await _execute();

    protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Perhaps something like using an `event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged`, which is used in ICommand and is reacted to by Button, instead of RaisePropertyChanged, but I'm out of ideas already.

I searched many places and tried many things to implement it, but without success.

Comment: This can be achieved without extending `Button` too. It depends how you want your button to be used. Do you want to bind two images to it and the toggle between them? Or are those images hardcoded into the button?

Comment: @BionicCode I planned to use StaticResource from App.xaml for the image and use a DataTrigger or something similar in the style of my x:CustomButton to react to changes in IsExecuting and change the Source for the Image. Unfortunately, it seems that for this, the button needs to have its own DataContext, which is not the case.

Comment: This is simply (button) "Content" and doesn't require a custom button. This falls under "attached behaviour".

Comment: @GerrySchmitz I agree with you, but my button will simply have an additional extra image passed through an Attached/Dependency Property like this: <x:CustomButton ImageSource={StaticResource ...} Command=...>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your behavior using a `Style` and a `DataTrigger`. You can define this `Style` as an application resource or as part of the default `Style` of your custom `Button`.

The following example shows how to toggle the `Button.Content` value. You can modify the trigger to toggle any other dependency property like an image source. It's not clear how your button looks like so I decided to show the trigger targeting the `Content` property:

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Content"
              Value="Not running" />

      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.IsExecuting}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Content"
                  Value="Command is Running..." />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

---

A note on your ICommand implementation: your command neither links the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event nor does it enable the client to raise it manually. The event is currently only raised after the command has been executed, which is pretty pointless.

What is the point of an `ExecuteAsync` when you don't make it public to add it to the commands API?

If you want to make `ExecuteAsync` virtual to allow inheritors to override it, you should consider to add the execute logic to this virtual method to enable inheritors to change the behavior in contrast to only adding behavior.Alternatively, define the `Icommand.Execute` implentation as virtual too.

Internally modifying the `CanExecute` condition by adding the `IsExecuting` condition is also questionable as it removes some of the flexibility of the way the type can be used.

Your code contains a typo: R***i***sePropertyChanged instead of R***ai***sePropertyChanged.

A suggested improved version of your `AsyncCommand`:

```cs
public class AsyncCommand : ViewModelBase, ICommand
{
  protected readonly Func<Task> _execute;
  protected readonly Func<bool>? _canExecute;

  private bool _isExecuting;
  public bool IsExecuting
  {
    get => _isExecuting;
    set => RisePropertyChanged(ref _isExecuting, value);
  }

  public bool IsCommandMangerRequerySuggestedEnabled { get; set; }

  public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> execute, Func<bool>? canExecute = null)
  {
    _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
    _canExecute = canExecute;

    this.IsCommandMangerRequerySuggestedEnabled = true;
    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += OnCommandManagerRequerySuggested;
  }

  private void OnCommandManagerRequerySuggested(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.IsCommandMangerRequerySuggestedEnabled)
    {
      this.CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
  }

  // Manually raise the CanExecuteChanged event
  public void InvalidateCommand()
    => this.CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

  public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

  public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => !_isExecuting && (_canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true);

  public async virtual void Execute(object? parameter)
  {
    if (CanExecute(parameter))
    {
      try
      {
        IsExecuting = true;
        await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
      }
      finally
      {
        IsExecuting = false;
      }
    }
  }

  public virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(object? parameter) => await _execute();

  protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: I used ExecuteAsync to make it easier to inherit AsyncCommand<T>: AsyncCommand. And I wrote all this 'on the fly' just as an example. Tnks

Comment: Wow! it seems to work just as needed. I still have to create CustomButton : Button since the button will also have an image passed like this: <x:CustomButton ImageSource={StaticResource ...} Command=...>.

Comment: It seems the problem was that I incorrectly specified the Binding, specifically I didn't think to use 'Command.IsExecuting'. Everything works fine with your example. Tomorrow, I'll try it on the product, but I think everything will work. Damn. Thank you very much! This thing took a lot of my time and nerves.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation and kindness. I'm happy I could help. Have a good time.